# issue with aws getCredentials nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to create a session token by using getCredentials() for accessing s3 objects.

The profile I am trying to switch to requires MFA authentication, I am getting the ***Error - InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.***  after entering the mfa token

here is the code snippet... any idea what am I doing wrong

```
import  { S3Client, ListBucketsCommand, ListObjectsV2Command } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';
import { fromIni } from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";
import * as readline from 'readline';

const bucketName = 'my-bucket-name';
const fq3Profile = 'my-profile-name'; // this profile is setup correctly in .aws/config..verified by console access
const awsRegion = 'my-region';

function prompt(query) {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout});
  
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      rl.question(query, (ans) => {
        rl.close();
        // console.log(`++++mfa token  - ${ans}`)
        resolve(ans);
      })
    );
}

const   getCredentials = async () =>  {
    return fromIni({
      profile: fq3Profile,
      mfaCodeProvider: async (serial) => prompt(
          `Enter mfa token for the account: ${serial}\n`
      ),
    });
  }

const s3client = new S3Client({ 
    region: awsRegion,
    credentials: await getCredentials()
});
```